# How to export data table to pdf using angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

I need to export my data table to a Pdf file using angular material and I don't know how can I do it exactly then guys plz guide me!

I have tried to use jsPDF and I found that it works on static data and I want to take a copy from my Datatable it should be a way to do that.

my HTML Datatable code source:

```
 <div class="content-card">
            <mat-table [dataSource]="listdata" matSort class="products-table" [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}"
                fusePerfectScrollbar>

                <!-- ID Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="icon">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Icon</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        <img src="{{element.UrlIconName}}"/>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Category Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Matricule">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxHide mat-sor   t-header fxShow.gt-md>Matricule</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxHide fxShow.gt-md>
                        <p class="category text-truncate">
                            {{element.FullName}}
                        </p>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Price Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Matricule2">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header fxHide fxShow.gt-xs>Matricule2</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs>
                        <p class="price text-truncate">
                            {{element.FullName2}}
                        </p>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Quantity Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Departemant">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>Departemant</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
                        <span>
                            {{element.DepartmentName}}
                        </span>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <!-- Quantity Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Etat">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>Etat d'inst
                    </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>

                        <p *ngIf="element.CurrentEquipmentElement; else notShow">
                            <mat-icon class="active-icon green-600 s-16">check</mat-icon>   
                        </p>
                        <ng-template #notShow>
                            <mat-icon class="active-icon red-500 s-16">close</mat-icon>
                        </ng-template>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

               <ng-container matColumnDef="Chauffeur">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>Chauffeur</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>
                        <span>
                            {{element.DriverName}}
                        </span>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
  ...

                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="product" matRipple></mat-row>


            </mat-table>
            <mat-toolbar color="white" >
                <mat-toolbar-row >
                    <mat-icon  title="Export as pdf" fxFlex="10">picture_as_pdf</mat-icon>
                    <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]" [pageSize]="5" fxFlex="90"></mat-paginator>
                </mat-toolbar-row>
            </mat-toolbar>
        </div>
        <!-- / CONTENT CARD -->
    </div>
```

My component.ts

```
 this.service.get_cars().subscribe((data)=>{
      //console.log(data);
      this.UIGestionlist = json2array(data);
 this.Listtrackigobjct = this.UIGestionlist[3];
      this.Listtrackigobjct.forEach(e=>{
this.listdata = new MatTableDataSource(this.Listtrackigobjct);
      this.listdata.sort = this.sort;
      this.listdata.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
```

I've tried using jspdf like:

```
downloadPdf() {
    this.Listtrackigobjct.forEach(e=>{
      const tempObj = {} as ExportArray;
      tempObj.FullName = e.FullName;
      tempObj.DepartmentName = e.DepartmentName;
      tempObj.DriverName = e.DriverName;
      tempObj.CurrentCarType = e.CurrentCarType;
      tempObj.CurrentCarModelString = e.CurrentCarModelString;
      tempObj.CurrentModelYear = e.CurrentModelYear;
      tempObj.CurrentFuelTypeEnum = e.CurrentFuelTypeEnum;
      tempObj.FuelContainerCapacity = e.FuelContainerCapacity;
      tempObj.MileageFloat = e.MileageFloat;
      prepare.push(tempObj);

    });
    console.log(prepare);
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({
        head: [['Matricule','Departemant','Chauffeur','Marque','Modele','Année','Type','Capacite','kilometrage']],
        body: prepare
    });
    doc.save('Vehicules_List' + '.pdf');
  }
}
```

but the pdf here just show me only the header as the picture here [image: the result]

and the body content is something like : [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

for example the first object: FullName: "Mat1"
{DepartmentName: "Dep1"
DriverName: "Ch1 Ali"
CurrentCarType: "Unknown"
CurrentCarModelString: "Autre Modèle"
CurrentModelYear: 2019
CurrentFuelTypeEnum: "Essence"
FuelContainerCapacity: 50
MileageFloat: 713}

Comment: u will not send data as [{}] if u look at my example data i answer array in array and all array is not object array they are string array u convert it to that style

Comment: Can u share one valid object

Comment: mmmm I see and how to convert that obj to array?

Comment: worst way is for loop and put them into array, best way is mapping . If u share one valid object i can write its code

Comment: [{FullName: "Mat1",DepartmentName: "Dep1",DriverName: "Ch1 Ali",CurrentCarType: "Unknown",CurrentCarModelString: "Autre Modèle",CurrentModelYear: 2019,CurrentFuelTypeEnum: "Essence",FuelContainerCapacity: 50,MileageFloat: 713},{FullName: "123"
,epartmentName: "Dep1",DriverName: "--",CurrentCarType: "Aston_martin",CurrentCarModelString: "Vantage",CurrentModelYear: 1900,CurrentFuelTypeEnum: "Essence",FuelContainerCapacity: 2,MileageFloat: 0}]

Comment: ok that object is enough? Or u want the model of obejrct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

U can use javascript typescript together . jspdf library can solve your problem. Import js pdf to your project

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import 'jspdf-autotable';


downloadPdf() {
    var prepare=[];
    this.Listtrackigobjct.forEach(e=>{
      var tempObj =[];
      tempObj.push(e.FullName);
      tempObj.push(e.DepartmentName);
      tempObj.push( e.CurrentCarType);
      tempObj.push( e.CurrentCarModelString);
      tempObj.push( e.CurrentModelYear);
      tempObj.push(e.CurrentFuelTypeEnum);
      tempObj.push(e.FuelContainerCapacity);
      tempObj.push(e.MileageFloat);
      prepare.push(tempObj);
    });
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({
        head: [['Matricule','','Departemant','','Chauffeur','','Marque','','Modele','','Année','','Type','','Capacite','','kilometrage']],
        body: prepare
    });
    doc.save('Vehicules_List' + '.pdf');
  }
}
```

Or u can use another way like i edited in stackblitz. use print function to write as pdf https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-export-excel-file-jescpr

```
 let printContents, popupWin;
    printContents = document.getElementById(tableId).innerHTML;
    console.log(printContents)
    popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=auto,width=auto');
    popupWin.document.open();
    popupWin.document.write(`
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Print tab</title>

    </head>
<body onload="window.print();window.close()"><table class="table table-bordered">${printContents}</table></body>
  </html>`
    );
    popupWin.document.close();
```

Comment: ok, but the body shouldn't be full data? I mean just if U have in ur response Log , Amount and age and U have to display just Log and Amount how to do that?

Comment: I didn'T understand what u mean? In head your will put it with your headers, and in body u will fill it with you data which u send it to html to show. head in this code is an example. U can make print function which take parameters that header and data .

Comment: Plz check my update. I did Ur proposition and It didn't works

Comment: Do u give an input to print function. How can it be a static data ? In body there will be a function input

Comment: great - after this answer we dont need to worry how many sub-table we have or not. simply frame new table based on data

Answer (score 4):

With TypeScript
[jsPdf autotable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf-autotable)

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import autoTable from 'jspdf-autotable'

  downloadPdf() {
    const doc = new jsPDF();
    autoTable(doc, { html: '#my_table_id' })
    doc.save('my_table.pdf')
  }
```

Comment: Easy and accurate answer